# How to show only one value from column postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date with three statuses: Open, Closed, Repairing. However, I am trying to show only the Open status value. I tried to use where clause, but it did not work. (Note: when where clause is used, there will be multiple open status which I did not want to show). Below is my current data after query:

[image]

This is the query from below answer

[image]

```
 select distinct on("id")*,
 status
 from ticket
 ORDER BY "id",CREATED DESC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get the first/last value with the status = Open? If so, do this.

```
 select distinct on("id") *, status
 from ticket where status = 'Open'
 ORDER BY id, CREATED DESC;
```

Comment: I am trying to get all the values of Open. If I create a new one, it must show 2. But now with you answer, it just shows 1

Comment: Then remove the LIMIT 1 at the end of the query. Edited the answer.

Comment: When i used this query, it shows all the open status. However, I am trying to sort date by descending and get the last value. i have added the output from ur query above

Comment: From the output above, i m trying to only show two open status because other two have been updated to other status

Comment: I need to compare the status with updated_status and just show the open status ticket.

Comment: I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 select distinct on("id") *, status, 
   CASE
     WHEN status='Open' THEN 1
   END 
 AS field3
 from ticket
 ORDER BY id, CREATED DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you want to get the tickets (`id`s) where the most recent status is `open` -- and only those.  If so, use `distinct on` in a subquery and filter afterwards:

```
select t.*
from (select distinct on (id) t.*,
      from ticket t
      order by id, created desc nulls last
     ) t
where t.status = 'open'
```